# Get specific class objects from HashSet in Java

Tags: java, class, iterator, set, hashset

I have a `public Set<ProjectItem> projectItems = new HashSet<ProjectItem>();` which can contains two types of classes (`ProjectItem` is a abstract super class for both of them). The classes are `Deliverable` and `Task`. I want get all objects of the class `Deliverable` from the `Set`. Therefore I write this:

```
public Set<Deliverable> allDeliverables(){
Set<Deliverable> result = new HashSet<Deliverable>();
for(Iterator<ProjectItem> iter = projectItems.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()){
    if (iter.next().getClass() == Deliverable.class){
    Deliverable del = (Deliverable) iter.next();
    result.add(del);
    }
}
return result;
}
```

But this makes an exception -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: edu.Chryb.ProjectManagement.Task cannot be cast to edu.Chryb.ProjectManagement.Deliverable

in the Line with: `Deliverable del = (Deliverable) iter.next();`

Is something in the if query wrong?

Thanks for every help.

Comment: It'll be a lot better to use a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is a bit out.  Try:

```
for(Iterator<ProjectItem> iter = projectItems.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()){
    ProjectItem item = iter.next();
    if (item.getClass() == Deliverable.class){
        result.add((Deliverable)item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the multiple invocations of `iter.next()` (because it return current element and forwards the cursor to the next element) within the loop.

Within the loop do something as follows first -

```
for(Iterator<ProjectItem> iter = projectItems.iterator(); iter.hasNext();){
    ProjectItem currItem = iter.next();
    //...
```

And then use `currItem` instead of calling `iter.next()` multiple times.

---

Side Note:

```
for(Iterator<ProjectItem> iter = projectItems.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()) {
```

The call `iter.next()` doesn't have to do with the mentioned problem but it shouldn't be there also. Because that you will skip actual current element.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `iter.next()` twice - once in the check, and once on the retrieval. It appears that you find a `Deliverable` followed by `Task`. The check of `Deliverable` succeeds, but the iterator moves on to `Task` right after that, so the following invocation of `next` returns a `Task`, not a `Deliverable`.

Change your code as follows:

```
for(Iterator<ProjectItem> iter = projectItems.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); iter.next()){
    ProjectItem next = iter.next();
    if (next.getClass() == Deliverable.class){
        Deliverable del = (Deliverable) next;
        result.add(del);
    }
}
```